# About python "#!usr/bin/env python"?

Tags: python, linux, zsh, shebang

I put "`#!usr/bin/env python`" at the first line in coroutine.py, but when I try to run coroutine.py directly by "`./test.py`", I get this:

`zsh: ./coroutine.py: bad interpreter: usr/bin/env: no such file or directory`

Is that something wrong in my zshrc?

Comment: You missed a slash.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use this at all. The person installing or otherwise using your script is the only one who knows where the necessary version of Python is stored. `distutils` uses replaces `#!python` with the correct path upon installation for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you missed the leading slash: `#!/usr/bin/env python` and it's called hashbang (and not a shebang wich is only the `#!` part as @cdarke explained in comments)

[More about shebang/hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: It's the `#!` that is called shebang because the `#` character is similar to the musical sharp character.  It is often called "hash-bang" because `#` is known as "hash" outside the USA.